# Javascript file does not load dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this answer, the [ever popular SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) to dynamically load a javascript file:

```
$.getScript("scripts/datagrid.js", function(){

    alert("Script loaded but not necessarily executed.");                      

});
```

But the it never loads.  JQuery is referenced in the underlying HTML file in the header **before** the js file that is calling this script loading function.  Furthermore, I don't call this script loader until after the document is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    administration.init();
});



var administration = {
    ...


   init : function() {

      try {

          $.getScript("scripts/datagrid.js", function(){
              alert("Script loaded but not necessarily executed.");

            });


       } catch (e) {
        alert('[administration.init] error = ' + e);
       }


   ...
```

I have validated that JQuery is loaded already by checking the value of an element that is hard-coded in HTML using JQuery.  Which is also validated by the fact the script is executed.

The script file exists and works if I add it to the HTML header, but I want to load it dynamically.

Why does the anonymous function never fire (obviously because the script never loads - why)?

**EDIT**

Following Sanjay's advice below, I bound the error handler to the ajax call and  the console now displays the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined(…)
```

So it's finding the file, just not apparently able to find the init function of the class.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your JavaScript console? Do you see the request made for the js file? (maybe it returns a 404 or something, or the wrong mime-type).

Comment: Check your console for other errors?

Comment: No errors in the console.

Comment: Maybe you're forgetting that a linked script in your page will be relative to the page while `$.getScript` will expect a url relative to the base address.  In other words if I'm viewing `http://www.testme.com/somefolder/index.html` and I try to load script in `http://www.testme.com/somefolder/scripts/datagrid.js`, a link to "scripts/datagrid.js" will work because it is relative to index.html but `$.getScript` will expect "somefolder/scripts/datagrid.js" for the same file.

Comment: Can you make plnkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: @Neil should the console have a 404 not found error then?

Comment: $.getScript is just a shortcut for $.ajax (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/). Could you use the long form and add an error handler?

Comment: @AndroidAddict No, because it is an ajax request.  You should be getting an ajax request failure, but you have no callback, so it gets ignored.

Comment: @Neil An ajax request still throw a 404 in the console even if there is no failure callback.

Comment: Try this form and report the error: `$.getScript( "scripts/datagrid.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    alert("exception:"+ exception );
});`

Comment: @Neil  Fully qualifying throws a 404 not found error on the file reference.

Comment: Next question is the URL accurate from the page relative point (same folder/scripts)? `scripts/datagrid.js` OR do you really need a root folder: `/scripts/datagrid.js`

Comment: @Hacketo You're sure?  I don't leave these things to chance.

Comment: @AndroidAddict do you have some Content-Security-Policy headers ?

Comment: @Hacketo  No content security policy headers.

Comment: Proof of jQuery put this in a page level script: `window.load = function(){
   alert(typeof jQuery);
}`  you have not loaded jQuery perhaps?  Show page portion where it does.

Comment: And are you sure your `$.getScript()` method is called at least??? EDIT!: ok so, have you try to bind `fail()` deferred method? **(see answer below!!!)** If ya, yhen if success not called, the error one would. Anyway, you have to learn how to debug js code. In your case if request failed, no not handled error will be thrown so your catch block is useless

Comment: @A.Wolff  Yes I have confirmed the line is getting executed.

Comment: @AndroidAddict So bind error handler of ajax method and you will get your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try to load `script` like

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    console.log( exception );  // here you can get reason why file is not loading 
});
```

you can see console error `Not Found` here [jsfiddl](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjaynishad/9qmv3qc9/)

Comment: Thank you.  But I want to know why this extremely popular post and answer are not working.

Comment: @AndroidAddict Because you are doing something wrong. You have to debug it, nothing we can help you

Comment: @AndroidAddict what's error are you getting? May be `$.getScript()` is not getting correct `script path`

Comment: I don't see any errors in the console nor are any raised in the try block the script is executed in.

Comment: @AndroidAddict `done` or `fail` method is executing of `getScript`? you should get something on `console` either `txtStatus`  or `exception`.

Answer (score 1):

Change code using the sequence like this: (remove try/hide and use event handler to debug this) call it AFTER you declare it.

```
if(!jQuery){alert("No jQuery loaded")}
var administration = {
  init : function() {
    $.getScript( "scripts/datagrid.js" )
    .done(function( script, textStatus ) { 
        console.log( textStatus );
    })
    .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) { 
        alert("exception:"+ exception ); 
    });
  }
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    administration.init();
});
```